Powershell script to delete old backups beyond a certain date
I'm trying to write a powershell script to delete old backups beyond a certain date. My folder would have a list of backups written every week or so.
My logic is to first find all the backups older than a certain date, and then remove those. So I would need to extract the date and the corresponding backups. I tried extracting these inside a foreach statement, but there seems to be something wrong with the syntax. Any advice on how to proceed with this?
My powershell script is below,
## Path
$path = "C:\SFTP_Root\SMGR"

## Get the current date
$Cur_dte = Get-Date
echo "Today is $Cur_dte"

## Old date (Subtract current date by 2 months i.e. 60 days)
$Old_dte = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)
echo "Old date is $Old_dte"

## Loop to extract the date and name of the backup)
foreach (($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $path | select -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime) -and ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $path | select -ExpandProperty Name))
    {
        if ($i -lt $Old_dte)
        {
        echo "$file is old; will be deleted"
        }
    elseif ($i -gt $Old_dte)
        {
        echo "$file is recent; won't be deleted"
        }
    }
    

And there are a lot of syntax errors in the foreach statement,
t C:\Temp\backups_clean.ps1:14 char:10
+ foreach (($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $path | select -ExpandProperty La ...
+          ~
Missing variable name after foreach.
At C:\Temp\backups_clean.ps1:14 char:14
+ foreach (($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $path | select -ExpandProperty La ...
+              ~~
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.
At C:\Temp\backups_clean.ps1:14 char:13
+ foreach (($i in Get-ChildItem -Path $path | select -ExpandProperty La ...
+             ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At C:\Temp\backups_clean.ps1:14 char:81
+ ... ChildItem -Path $path | select -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime) -and ($ ...
+                                                                 ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At C:\Temp\backups_clean.ps1:14 char:95
+ ...  $path | select -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime) -and ($file in Get-Chi ...
+                                                                ~~
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.
At C:\Temp\backups_clean.ps1:14 char:94
+ ... ath $path | select -ExpandProperty LastWriteTime) -and ($file in Get- ...
+                                                                  ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At C:\Temp\backups_clean.ps1:14 char:153
+ ... d ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $path | select -ExpandProperty Name))
+                                                                        ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
At C:\Temp\backups_clean.ps1:14 char:154
+ ... d ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $path | select -ExpandProperty Name))
+                                                                         ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingVariableNameAfterForeach


You can't use two variables inside a for loop like this. Instead iterate over all the files and access their properties inside the loop:
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem -Path $path) {
    if ($file.LastWriteTime -lt $Old_dte) {
        echo "$file is old; will be deleted"
    }
    else {
        echo "$file is recent; won't be deleted"
    }
}

As a side-note: I'd avoid using two conditions with -lt and -gt. What if the date is exactly the same? If you use only one condition it's clear, what will happen to those files.

You are overthinking
# Set the path of the directory containing the files.   
$DirectoryPath = 'C:\SFTP_Root\SMGR'

# Set the date before when you want do delete the files.  
$CutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)

# Get all files(and only files) in $DirectoryPath.   
Get-ChildItem -File -Path $DirectoryPath | 
    # Keep only those created before $CreationDate.  
    Where-Object -Property CreationTime -LT $CutoffDate | 
    # REMOVE VAGA... I mean: delete them.   
    Remove-Item

replace CreationDate with LastWriteTime if necessary
